# How can i change my code to include my second photo in my carousel?

Tags: php, echo, carousel

I deleted my original slide 2 and then tried to add my new slide in. Didn't work. Even tried saving new slide as the old slide name thinking that would work.

Currently on my website the first slide in the carousel works, but the second is blank. Unsure whether it's size, but sure it's because i deleted the old one.

How can i get create correct echo link?

Tried changing font but with echo it's not creating the right link.

```
<section id="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php
                $slides = get_banner('homepage_banner_slider');
                foreach ($slides as $idx=>$slide) {
            ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $idx==0 ? 'active' : ''; ?> item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $slide['image']; ?>')">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <span class="title">
                        <?php echo $slide['title']; ?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">
                        <?php echo $slide['description']; ?>
                    </span>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <?php
                            $buttons = $slide['buttons'];
                            foreach ($buttons as $button) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $button['link']; ?>" class="btn-two <?php echo $button['class']; ?> ease"><?php echo $button['text']; ?></a>

                           <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

I want the second slide to show up on my website without having to add 'href' link

Comment: what is the content of `$slides`? An array yes, but can you add a var_dump to show the contents?

Comment: Thanks! I had a look, and it said it was the destination of the image i was trying to show. I then had a look on a different browser and the image loaded. Turns out the image is way to big to load quickly at work. But my home computer can ;). Thanks @RamRaider